# SQL Query ORDER BY issue - doesn't appear to be sorting as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns the values as expected however the ORDER BY doesn't appear to work at all on the last column (totalPointsSum) which is an alias column.

An example of how this data looks is shown below.. obviously I want 6200 first, 400 second and 50 third sorted by the totalPointsSum - any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

```
+---------+----------+----------------+
| user_id | username | totalPointsSum |
| 5555555 |    bob   |      6200      |
| 6666666 |   geoff  |       50       |
| 7777777 |    lee   |      400       |
+---------|----------|----------------+
```

My table structure is as follows:

```
myusers(user_id, username);
organisations(organisation_id, organisation_name);
codes(redeemed_code_id, user_id, unique_code, date_redeemed, school_points, inactive);
```

My query is as follows..

```
        SELECT
        t.*, (
            SELECT
                COALESCE (SUM(x.school_points), "0")
            FROM
                codes x
            WHERE
                x.user_id = t.user_id
            AND x.school_points > 0
            AND x.inactive = 0
            AND (
                x.date_redeemed >= 1393286400
                OR x.date_redeemed = 0
            )
        ) AS totalPointsSum
    FROM
        `myusers` `t`
    INNER JOIN organisation o ON (
        t.organisation_id = o.organisation_id
    )
    WHERE
        o.organisation_id = 25679
    ORDER BY totalPointsSum desc
```

P.S I'll add a sqlfiddle shortly

Comment: try:     ORDER BY LENGTH(totalPointsSum) desc, totalPointsSum desc

Comment: AWESOME! Please leave this as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, remove the double quotes from around the 0 in the `COALESCE` function. The will eliminate the implicit data conversion that's happening, and allow the expression to be numeric.

```
COALESCE(SUM(x.school_points),  0  )
                               ^ ^
```

You could also use the MySQL `IFNULL` function

```
IFNULL(SUM(x.school_points),0)
```

Either way, that's going to be numeric column passed to the outer query, so then the `ORDER BY` will handle it as a numeric, rather than a character string.

---

When you use `COALESCE` on expressions of two different datatypes (e.g. a numeric and a character string), there's an implicit conversion of one or the other, so that the column being returned is a single datatype.

What you've got happening in your original statement is an **implicit** data conversion that essentially equivalent to *explicitly* expressing:

```
 COALESCE(CAST( SUM(x.school_points) AS VARCHAR(50)), '0')
          ^^^^^                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you remove those quotes around the zero, that changes that zero from a *string* literal into a *numeric* literal. And that means that the `SUM()` won't have to be cast to character type.

Comment: the other solution worked with the query - but this fix was the ideal solution as it meant my Yii functionality needed no changing so therefore was the better solution. thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on this line:

```
COALESCE (SUM(x.school_points), "0")
```

The string `"0"` forces the type of the value computed by the inner query (`totalPointsSum`) to string. Consequently, `ORDER BY totalPointsSum desc` sorts the strings `"6200"`, `"50"` and `"400"` and does it well.

Change `"0"` (string) to `0` (number) and the query will run as you want.

Comment: it's the `COALESCE` function that's causing an implicit datatype conversion; the expression has to return a *single* datatype. This solution allows the `COALESCE` expression to return a *numeric* rather than a *string*.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your inner SELECT's returned value is being treated as a string instead of an integer.

Try adding a zero (this should it force it to be treated like a number):

```
 ORDER BY totalPointsSum+0 DESC
```

---

Side note:

You might verify that the `school_points` is actually an `INT` field. If it's not, just changing it to an `INT` field might be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please try ORDER BY LENGTH(totalPointsSum) desc, totalPointsSum desc;

This way it will simulate natural order.

Comment: This is a kludge. Better approach is to actually fix the datatype of the expression. I'm tempted to test this "solution" with some negative values, and some values that have digits after the decimal point, to demonstrate the inadequacy of this solution.